# Passing same object context 2 two separate view controllers

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a managedObject that is being passed from 1 view controller to another the first pass works fine but when I try to pass the next object after the relationship has been set it doesn't send anything and comes back as either nil or if I try to use other methods comes back with a syntax error. The code I am using for the view controllers is as follows

View Controller 1, The first object set:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        switch identifier {
        case "popOver":
            if let VC = segue.destinationViewController as? ClassDeckNameViewController
            {
                if let ppc = VC.popoverPresentationController {
                    VC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
                    ppc.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any
                    ppc.delegate = self

                }

                VC.classSave = (sender as! ClassSelection)
            }
        default: break
        }
    }

}
@IBAction func buttonPriest(sender: AnyObject) {


    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ClassSelection", inManagedObjectContext: classMOC!)

    let newObject = ClassSelection(entity: entity!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext: classMOC)

    newObject.classname = "Priest"

    var error: NSError?

    if let err = error {

        println(err)

    } else {

        classMOC?.save(&error)

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("popOver", sender: newObject)


    }

}
```

This passes the object without problem to the second view controller but this is the one that won't pass any further to the final presenting controller offering the user the final selections for their "Deck":

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showCardSelection" {
        let detailVC: CardSelectionViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CardSelectionViewController
        detailVC.passedDeckObject = (sender as! Deck)
    }
}
@IBAction func enterButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Deck",inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

    let storeDeck = Deck(entity: entityDescription!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    storeDeck.deckname = usersDeckName.text
    storeDeck.classSelected = classSave!

    var error: NSError?

    managedObjectContext?.save(&error)

    if let err = error {

        status.text = err.localizedFailureReason


    } else {

        usersDeckName.text = ""
        status.text = "Deck Saved"
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showCardSelection", sender: storeDeck)

    }

}
```

I made passedDeckObject a variable of type Deck? in the final view controller to set the final relationship methods I know I am doing something wrong but I am unsure what! Any help with this would be amazing!

Comment: Did you check that you have a context so you can create the instance? Also, why do you have `var error: NSError?` then immediately `if let err = error {` ?

Comment: As far as the error part of the code goes that was what was recommended to me by another developer as a test to see that the app was working. I will be cutting out that section once all functions of the app are stable. What method would I use to check to see if I have a context? I know that both the deckname and classSelected are storing in core data as I can pull them up on a separate tableview without issue.

Comment: Just add some logging to check that they're created and they're received - where is the first place something isn't available?

Comment: `Optional(<Hearthstone_Mobile_Stat_Tracker_Pro.Deck: 0x7c2780f0> (entity: Deck; id: 0x7c2e74f0 <x-coredata://10A07653-DF25-4571-AF3C-18FA12844B38/Deck/p6> ; data: {
    cardspicked =     (
    );
    classSelected = "0x7c29e7d0 <x-coredata://10A07653-DF25-4571-AF3C-18FA12844B38/ClassSelection/p11>";
    deckname = test;
    recordedstats =     (
    );
}))
Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' (0x1c6027c) to 'Hearthstone_Mobile_Stat_Tracker_Pro.Deck' (0xcbc68).
(lldb)` this is everything that goes up until the time the enter button is hit on the second view controller.

Comment: The object shows in the second view controller and saves in the second view controller just fine but when I try to pass the object to the third view controller it either returns nil or crashes with some error.

Comment: It reads like you've connected a segue directly to the button rather than the target/action for `enterButton`

Comment: Wow...I am amazed at myself for not figuring that out myself...the problem was I haven't looked at my storyboard in weeks as this is my first project I have been working on the backend only. After taking a look at the view controller I noticed that the enter button was directly connected instead of going from view controller to view controller and calling it programmatically. The object is passing fine as I can print the deckname in the next view controller after the viewdidload. Thank you for dealing with my beginners mistake.

Comment: In this instance what should I do should I post a answer myself explaining what went wrong or do you and I accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a misconfiguration issue where the segue is being triggered directly in the storyboard rather than calling your code. As such the `sender` is a button rather than the new entity instance you're expecting.

To fix, disconnect the segue in the storyboard and connect (if it isn't already) the button to your action method in the view controller.